# Elastic collision of photon

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, collision

Consider an elastic collision of a photon with 100 eV energy hitting a mirror. How much momentum is exchanged in the collision?

Also, can one model the reflection of an elastically colliding photon with a single electron in the mirror? It would seem that the photon would be absorbed by the electron, so that the collision is necessarily inelastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, practically, if a photon of 100eV (XUV) hit a mirror, it would go right through or collide with the particles inside and get absorbed. If you are thinking of light, then if the photon is reflected, it direction is changed, and therefore its velocity is changed and therefore, it will have had to exchange momentum with the electrons in the atoms of the mirror. This is well explained by the drude model where the photon excites the electron and is re-emitted with only its direction changed but everything else remaining the same.  ([Elastic scattering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_scattering) means only change of direction and not energy).

Comment: Hm, what about if the photon had 1 eV energy? I am aware that momentum would have been exchanged, but is it just $E_k=p^2/2m$ for $m$ the electron mass? I'd also like to know under which conditions a photon would get absorbed during collision.

Comment: I was referring to that energy level when I mentioned light. In case of metal, absorption is very low. In case of semiconductors, the absorption starts at the band gap and goes like $ (E_g - hw)^{1/2} $ above the band gap, excluding excitonic absorption which may occur in pure materials and at low temperatures.

Comment: So in the case of a mirror/metal, assuming that absorption is very low the momentum should change from $p$ to $-p$ and $2p$ momentum is exchanged in the collision, where $p=\frac{E}{c}$? If there were a single electron in this metal, how would the photon reflect? Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: When the photon is absorbed by the electron, it is no longer in existence (photons can be created and destroyed). What comes out when the electron relaxes back to its previous state is a new photon with the same frequency but different direction. The direction can be determined by the Feynman path integral formulation i.e. sum the amplitudes for an event to occur. I suggest you read his book on QED (half the book is devoted to this fascinating question)